# SSRS Web Portal and Service URL showing "This site can't be reached"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, configurationmanager

[image: This is the Web Portal Configuration]
[image: This is the Web Service Configuration. I have added a SSl certificate in it and verified it.]
The logs are also fine still getting this error on clicking the URL. I have opened the Browser in Admin mode and also added the urls in trusted sites but nothing working.
[image: That's the browser screenshot]

These are the log files

```
2023-03-26 02:56:07.9745|INFO|1|File Logger created: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles\RSHostingService_2023_03_26_02_56_07.log - level Info, will roll at 32 Mb, process id 1740
2023-03-26 02:56:08.0155|INFO|1|Current Directory : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\RSHostingService
2023-03-26 02:56:08.4885|INFO|5|Updating application config files
2023-03-26 02:56:08.4885|INFO|5|Syncing service machine key
2023-03-26 02:56:08.5265|INFO|5|Catalog max connection pool size: 100
2023-03-26 02:56:08.5815|INFO|5|Launching Process : Management Service
2023-03-26 02:56:08.5815|INFO|5|Starting Process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\Management\RSManagement.exe
2023-03-26 02:56:31.3671|INFO|4|<Header>
  <Product>Microsoft Power BI Report Server  (16.0.1113.11)</Product>
  <Locale>English (United States)</Locale>
  <TimeZone>UTC--4</TimeZone>
  <Path>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles\RSHostingService_2023_03_26_02_56_07.log</Path>
  <SystemName>EC2AMAZ-OH9JMJO</SystemName>
  <OSName>Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter</OSName>
  <OSVersion>10.0.17763</OSVersion>
  <ProcessID>1740</ProcessID>
  <Virtualization>True</Virtualization>
</Header>
<ProcessorArchitecture>AMD64</ProcessorArchitecture>
<ApplicationArchitecture>AMD64</ApplicationArchitecture>
```

```
2023-03-26 03:18:29.1111|INFO|1|File Logger created: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles\RSManagement_2023_03_26_03_18_29.log - level Info, will roll at 32 Mb, process id 5492
2023-03-26 03:18:29.1891|INFO|1|Do not dump on: Microsoft.BIServer.HostingEnvironment.Exceptions.TrustedProcessTokenExpiredException
2023-03-26 03:18:29.2291|INFO|1|SKU: SQL Server Developer
2023-03-26 03:18:29.4071|INFO|1|The web server needs to run elevated
2023-03-26 03:18:29.4071|INFO|1|Web Server is running.
2023-03-26 03:18:48.6187|INFO|4|<Header>
  <Product>Microsoft Power BI Report Server  (16.0.1113.11)</Product>
  <Locale>English (United States)</Locale>
  <TimeZone>UTC--4</TimeZone>
  <Path>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles\RSManagement_2023_03_26_03_18_29.log</Path>
  <SystemName>EC2AMAZ-OH9JMJO</SystemName>
  <OSName>Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter</OSName>
  <OSVersion>10.0.17763</OSVersion>
  <ProcessID>5492</ProcessID>
  <Virtualization>True</Virtualization>
</Header>
<ProcessorArchitecture>AMD64</ProcessorArchitecture>
<ApplicationArchitecture>AMD64</ApplicationArchitecture>
```

I have tried the Service configuration for all assigned IPs and without certificates but that also don't work for me. Also I added the Url IPs to listen list. Running the browser for admin and added the urls in trusted sites. Nothing is working.

I just want to run the reporting manager normally.